# Реализация верстки на флексбоксах

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Имеется 3 блока sidebar, navbar и main. Как без дополнительных оберток реализовать то что на картинке?

```
.sidebar
.navbar
.main
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пояснение из комментариев**

Под обертками я понимаю лишние классы (`.wrapper`, `.content`). Это невозможно реализовать без дополнительных классов?

Comment: Без обёрток никак не реализовать

Comment: спасибо, даже используя grid layout?

Comment: Даже и не знал про grid layout. Просмотрел одну статейку. Если <section> тоже считается обёрткой, то очевидно нельзя. А так вроде можно. Похоже на таблицу, только строки и колонки прописываются в css. Вот Вам статейка https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/140715/ на всякий случай

Comment: спасибо еще раз

Comment: Сам уже было раскатал губу на grid layout. Но тут же пришлось закатать обратно. Никем, кроме ie, не поддерживается. Да и ie как-то странно поддерживает. Пришлось все аттрибуты `grid-*` переписать на `-ms-grid-*` В общем сплошной обман этот grid

Comment: Кроме IE? Откуда информация? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @tutankhamun уверен по вашей ссылке просто перепутали.

Comment: @Sergey это я не дочитал. В таблице сноски есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал в качестве контейнера для флекса задействовать `body` и направить флекс по колонкам. Но чтобы блоки начали переноситься в новую колонку, понадобилось задать для `body` точную высоту (`min-height` для этого недостаточно). Из-за этого макет перестал тянуться по вертикали.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 180px;
}
.sidebar {
  background: #69c;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 30%; 
}
.navbar {
  background: #c69;
  height: 60px; 
  width: 70%;
}
.main {
  background: #9c6;
  height: calc(100% - 60px); 
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div class="navbar">navbar</div>
<div class="main">main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main</div>
```

Если убрать боковую панель под навигацию, то флекс пойдёт по строкам и макет будет тянуться по вертикали:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.sidebar {
  background: #69c;
  flex-basis: 30%; 
}
.navbar {
  background: #c69;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.main {
  background: #9c6;
  flex-basis: 70%; 
}
.sidebar,
.navbar,
.main {
  min-height: 60px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">navbar</div>
<div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div class="main">main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main</div>
```

Comment: Gleb а почему блок в вашем случае не тянется ?

Comment: @Geyan В первом примере я направил флекс по вертикали и задал высоту для `body`, чтобы блоки знали, когда переходить в новый столбец. Поэтому нижняя граница блока `main` зафиксировалась и хвост контента оказался снаружи.

Answer (score 2):

Не видя ваш код, не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под

> без дополнительных оберток

Можно попробовать сделать с помощью flexbox.

[MDN CSS Flexible Box Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)
[MDN Using CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
aside {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
nav {
  background: orangered;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
main {
  background: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside>sidebar</aside>
  <div class="content">
    <nav>navbar</nav>
    <main>main</main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: под обертками я понимаю лишние классы (wrapper, content) 
Это невозможно реализовать без дополнительных классов?

Comment: Это не дополнительные обёртки, а совершенно необходимые контейнеры, без которых флекса в принципе не существует.

Comment: display: flex;
  position: absolute;
это шутка ведь, верно ?

Answer (score 1):

обычный способ:

```css
.sidebar{
  background-color:#72DCC3;
  height:300px;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
}

.navbar{
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
}

.main{
  background-color:gray;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div class="navbar">navbar</div>
<div class="main">main</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но вопрос был именно в верстке на флексбоксах

Comment: как я понял флекбоксы предполагают равномерное распределение а у вас не равномерное. могу ошибаться...

Comment: Пример притянут за уши. Если бы везде можно было бы выставить фиксированную высоту флекс и грид вообще не стали бы придумывать